# Laravel Foreach Nested or change my function?

Tags: laravel

I'm a newbie, studying programming.
Doing Laravel.

My table looks like this

```
ID  FormID  Type
1   1       Regional
2   1       Remote
3   1       Metro
4   2       Regional
5   2       Remote
6   3       Regional
7   3       Remote
```

My controller

`$FormID = WorkArea::select('FormID', 'Type')->get();`

My View is this

```
@foreach( $WorkArea as $WorkAreas)
                      <tr></tr>
                           <td>  {{ $WorkAreas->FormID}}  </td
                           <td>  {{ $WorkAreas->Type}}  </td>
@endforeach
```

Question:

How to foreach loop to show something like this in my VIEW

```
Form ID        Type
1          Regional Remote Metro
2          Regional Remote
3          Regional Remote
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Collection to help transform the structure for you:

```
$workAreas = WorkArea::get(['FormID', 'Type'])
    ->groupBy('FormID')
    ->map->pluck('Type');

@foreach ($workAreas as $FormID => $types)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $FormID }}</td>
        <td>{{ $types->join(' ') }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Method `groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Method `map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Method `pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Method `join`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Higher Order Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages)

Comment: I followed this. Thank you so much.

i also added leftjoin so that instead of using FormID, i used description of that ID

    $Rates = DB::table('work_areas')
    ->leftjoin('forms', 'forms.ID', '=','work_areas.formID')
    ->get(['forms.Doc_Desc', 'work_areas.Type',])->groupBy('Doc_Desc')->map->pluck('Type');

Answer (score 0):

try this
in your controller

```
$workAreas = WorkArea::select('FormID', 'Type')->get();
```

in your View

```
@if(! empty($workAreas))
  @foreach($workAreas as $workArea)
     <tr>
        <th>{{ $work->FormID }}</th>
        <th>
          @foreach($workAreas as $work)
             @if($workArea->FormID === $work->FormID)
               {{ $work->Type }}
             @endif
         @endforeach
       </th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```